# Seeking practical guidance on lighting Hanukka candles outside

Tags: menora-chanukia

I am thinking about lighting Hanukka candles outside my home this year (motivated by recent events in Israel and worldwide).

A little web search did not turn up any step by step instructions on building a container to protect the candles from wind or instruction on lighting outdoors (e.g., how to deal with wind).

Seeking instructions for building an outside menora and lighting instructions.

Comment: Everyone I've seen do this uses a glass box like the one shown in this picture https://www.amazon.com/Art-Judaica-Menorah-31x40x20-Holders/dp/B08YWWCV57

Comment: Please note the price on that model is significantly higher than average, it was chosen just because it happened to be a good picture

Comment: alternatively you can get a bigger box designed to put a full-sized menorah inside it, however these can get a bit expensive. The idea is that these boxes 1. protect the menorah from the wind 2. allow for easy access in lighting the candles and 3. provide enough air that they can burn without getting blown out.

Comment: @יהושעק  
Thx. Yes, a less expensive one is here: https://www.shopeichlers.com/products/menorah-box-small/50383